# сменить название кнопки после клика

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Файл js:

```
function favorite(id) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "favorite.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { id: id }
   });
}
```

php:

```
$id = text($_POST['id']);
if ($id){
    $q = DB::$dbs->prepare("SELECT * FROM `favorite` WHERE `stantion_id` = ? AND `user` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $q->execute([$id,App::user()->id]);
    if (!$no = $q->fetchObject()) {
    $q = DB::$dbs->prepare("INSERT INTO `favorite` (`stantion_id`,`user`) VALUES (?,?)");
    $q->execute([$id,App::user()->id]);
    $ok = 'add';
    }
    else
    {
    DB::$dbs->query("DELETE FROM `favorite` where `stantion_id` = ? AND `user` = ?",array($id,App::user()->id));
    $ok = 'del';
    }
}

$out = array(
    'ok' => $ok,
);

header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode($out);
```

html:

```
<button onclick="favorite('<?= $id ?>'); return false;">В избранное</button>
```

После клику по кнопке, нужно заменить надпись на кнопке

```
<button onclick="favorite('<?= $id ?>'); return false;">Удалить с избранного</button>
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: А ответ от сервера какой приходит? (Network)

Comment: @doox911, обновил первый пост.
смысл такой, если нет записи в БД- кнопка "добавить", есть записть - кнопка "удалить".

Comment: У васзапрос успешно отрабатывает?  Что в ответе? Или он вообще не отрабатывает?

Comment: @doox911, запрос всегда успешно обратывает по клику. или делает запись в БД, или удаляет его.

Comment: Request URL: http://radio/favorite.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: А в самом ответе что?

Comment: спасибо за помощь, дважды спросили одно и тоже.
что за люди такие, просишь помочь,а они издиваються.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96464/discussion-between-doox911-and-a).

Comment: Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://bit.ly/2UOXtOr), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/223536).

Answer (score 0):

Можно менять к примеру так:

```js
function favorite(el, id) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "favorite.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: id
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    el.innerText = response.data.ok == 'add' ? "Удалить с избранного" : "В избранное";
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="favorite(this, '<?= $id ?>')">В избранное</button>
```

Естественно проверку уже решите для себя сами, в зависимости от того, что вернул сервер.

Comment: Ну так поэтому вас спрашивали выше что приходит в ответе от сервера, и тогда можно сделать проверку.

Comment: Да, там запрос, ответа нет, если это весь php то нужно вернуть результат, и в зависимости от него менять или нет наименование.

Comment: Не вижу вверху succes но код подправил должно работать.